# Creating a "database"

Tags: python

What i'm trying to learn is how to allow a user to create a list of names then attach a number to each of the names for the user to look up afterwards. I'm not even sure if Database is the right term for this.

I'm able to allow the user to create a list of numbers, but I dont know how to, let the user make a list of names, and attach the two so the user can just look up a name and find their score after they create the lists.

```
list_of_nums = []
loop = True
while loop == True:
    try: num = int(input("Enter Integer, 0 to end: "))
    except ValueError: num = "invalid"
    if num == "invalid": print("\nPlease Print A Valid Integer!\n");
    elif num != 0: list_of_nums.append(num)
    else: loop = False
print(list_of_nums)
```

Comment: Database isn't the correct term for this, because all the data will be lost when your program terminates.

Comment: On another note, this isn't Java.

Comment: Should this be retagged python?

Comment: Yeah my bad, I meant python

Comment: @Gendarme Persistence is not a criteria for a database.

Comment: Sounds like you want a [dict](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). This will make an association between the names and the numbers. I don't recommend you try to learn about fundamentals of the language piecemeal from us. Read a dedicated book or tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

you should start by studying pickle: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Once you get the general idea, master the use of sqlite. [The raw sqlite please](https://sqlite.org/cli.html), in order to get yourself exposed to the SQL language. This is not ansi sql but is popular and close enough.

[Then use some query builder](https://www.sqlalchemy.org) to help you to get able to master [your](http://initd.org/psycopg/) [next](https://pypi.org/project/MySQL-python/) [data](https://pypi.org/project/cx-Oracle/)[ba](https://pypi.org/project/pymssql/)[se](https://pypi.org/project/ibm-db/).

Finally, regarding your problem with numbers, names and scores, try either to use the same loop to ask all the needed information or use more loops.

I have a feeling that you're learning python, so you could take the codecademy.com python course. It could save you from a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to save temporary this inputs in the list you should do this:

```
list_of_nums = []

num = 1

while num:
    try:
        num = int(input("Enter a integer, 0 to end: "))
    except:
        print("Enter a integer number")
    list_of_nums.append(num)

print(list_of_nums)
```

EDIT:

But if you want to pair values, its better to use dictionaries:

```
grades = {}

num = 1

while True:
    try:
        name = input("Name: ")
        num = int(input("Grade, -1 to end: ")) # the person can also take 0!
    except:
        print("ENTER A INTEGER NUMBER!")
        continue

    if num == -1:
        break # break the loop

    # if <num> isn't between 0 and 10:
    if num < 0 or num > 10: # or the minimum and max values you want
        print("ENTER A GRADE BETWEEN 0 AND 10!")
        continue

    grades[name] = num # You can acess <num> with grades[name]


#SHOW THE GRADES IN ALPHABETIC ORDER
grades_in_order = []
#thats how you iterate a dictionary
#you get the keys with a for, and access that key like a list index
for name in grades:
    grades_in_order.append(name)

grades_in_order.sort()

print("\n\nGrades:")

for name in grades_in_order:
    print(name, grades[name], sep='\t') # the sep is optional
```

Here is run example:

```
Name: Iago
Grade, -1 to end: Invalid
ENTER A INTEGER NUMBER!
Name: Hano
Grade, -1 to end: 11
ENTER A GRADE BETWEEN 0 AND 10!
Name: Iago
Grade, -1 to end: -2
ENTER A GRADE BETWEEN 0 AND 10!
Name: Hano
Grade, -1 to end: 10
Name: Iago
Grade, -1 to end: 10
Name: Nick
Grade, -1 to end: 0
Name: Mary
Grade, -1 to end: 9
Name: Jane
Grade, -1 to end: 7
Name: DOESNT MATTER
Grade, -1 to end: -1


Grades:
Hano    10
Iago    10
Jane    7
Mary    9
Nick    0
```

Comment: ok thank you, but how do I then, have a list where you add names and pair them with the grades?